# How to change the order of dodged bar plot with two factor levels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom

I have a bar plot in R using

```
ggplot2::geom_bar(data = data,
           mapping = ggplot2::aes(
             x = values_for_x,
             y = values_for_y,
             color = factor_levels_for_color,
             fill = factor_levels_for_color,
             alpha = factor_levels_for_alpha
           ),
           position = ggplot2::position_dodge2(
             preserve = "total"
           ),
           stat = "identity",
           linewidth = 0
         )
```

As you can see, I have 3 different columns defining `color`, `fill` and `alpha`.
Currently, my dodged bars are first ordered/grouped by `alpha` and the by `color`. However, I would like to have them first ordered by the `color` and then by `alpha`.

I am currently stuck finding the right position to define this.
Any help/hint is appreciated!

Thanks!

## Update incl. code example.

The following code plots a ggplot. It does order all dodged bars first by the levels of the `alpha` value, then using the `color_values` factor levels.
I would like to switch this, but fail so far to do this.

While this is a minimal example, my code defines the levels manually and also assigns specific color or alpha values to certain values that I do not want to change.

Thanks again!

```
data <- base::data.frame(
  x_values = rep(x = c("Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3"), times = 3),
  y_values = c(5,8,7,3,7,8,3,1,5),
  alpha_values = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  group = "A",
  color_values = c("location1", "location1", "location1",
                   "location2", "location2", "location2",
                   "location3", "location3", "location3")
)

data2 <- base::data.frame(
  x_values = rep(x = c("Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3"), times = 3),
  y_values = c(17,18,17,13,17,18,13,11,15),
  alpha_values = c(7,7,7,3,3,3,5,5,5),
  group = "B",
  color_values = c("location3", "location3", "location3",
                   "location1", "location1", "location1",
                   "location2", "location2", "location2")
)

data <- dplyr::bind_rows(base::list(data, data2))

data$alpha_values <- base::as.factor(data$alpha_values)
data$group <- base::as.factor(data$group)
data$color_values <- base::as.factor(data$color_values)

ggplot2::ggplot(data = data,
                mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x_values,
                              y = y_values,
                              alpha = alpha_values,
                              fill = color_values)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = ggplot2::position_dodge2())
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working code and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: You appear to have already created `factor`s, but did you explicitly give the order of the factor `levels`? That can be done either on instantiation with `factor(x, levels=c(...))` or afterwards with `levels(x) <- c(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I am adding now a "minimal" example. (Even though it might not look minimal, sorry about that). Yes, I assigned already factor levels and manual scales for these factor levels in ggplot2. The question is explained in more detail in the "edited" version of my original post... coming now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be to make a factor that combines the color and alpha values, and order it the way you want. For instance you can order it using multiple variables using `dplyr::arrange`, and then make a new factor variable that respects that compound order using `forcats::fct_inorder`:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = data |>
                  dplyr::arrange(color_values, alpha_values) |>
                  dplyr::mutate(order = forcats::fct_inorder(paste(color_values, alpha_values))),
                mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x_values,
                                       y = y_values,
                                       alpha = alpha_values,
                                       fill = color_values,
                                       group = order)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = ggplot2::position_dodge2())
```

[image]

In very limited circumstances you could skip the "new combined factor" step and use `group = interaction(alpha_values, color_values)` in your `aes()` to get the same result -- **provided your factors are alphanumerically ordered like in your example case**. `?interaction` says the result is unordered, but in your example the factors are alphanumerically ordered, so `interaction(data$alpha_values, data$color_values)` outputs  `[1] 1.location1 2.location1 3.location1 1.location2 ...`), which happens to have the order you want. This won't work in most cases, though, e.g. if the numbers exceed 9, or if the factors don't happen to be alphabetically ordered.

In some circumstances, it might suffice to add `group = color_values` to tell ggplot2 that the dodging should be done (primarily) based on `color_values`, and not by `alpha_values`. Dodging behaviour is specified by the `group` aesthetic, and it appears that when it is not specified, but `color` and `alpha` are,  the default is to group by the `alpha` mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had a hunch that a variable combining both factor level columns is one solution. I was hoping for something more straight forward, especially since I am supplying the factor levels manually etc. (my real code is a bit more complex). But maybe your route is the only option out there... Thanks!

Comment: I will give your "interaction" solution a try later. In the meantime however, I was changing my "location" factor level to numbers (basically removing the location prefix), because I wanted to see if this changes anything (because now, the alpha and color levels have 1, 2, 3, thus should be indistinguishable on that level). The result in ggplot however is the same, raising the question: What is ggplot using to determine the order in such a case?

Comment: In your example case, at least, it's also sufficient to add `aes(group = color_values)`. Curious if that works for your real case too.

Comment: That works. Yes. Thank you so much for pointing this out! But I have to admit I have to think about why this works. So far, I did not use the `group` argument in ggplot's `aes` to target this kind of behavior. But it works so... thanks so much for your swift help. Highly appreciated!

Comment: `position` adjustments, like dodge, work using the `group` aesthetic. When it's not assigned explicitly, ggplot2 uses heuristics to guess which other mapped variable should be used to define grouping. This often is sufficient. It appears that when both alpha and color are mapped to factors, ggplot2's default is to use the alpha one first. We can override this if we want it to look to the color variable first.